# Variable not getting replaced in Unix

Tags: database, shell, variables, unix

Given this code:

```
L_count=12
echo "hi hello $l_count"
```

The expected output is:

```
hi hello 12
```

If I run the code it gives the result as desired.

However, I have problems working in databases:

Now I am inserting the same string 'hi hello $l_count' in col1 of test table:

```
Insert into test(col1) values ('hi hello $l_count');
```

In UNIX:

```
l_count=12
var1=sqlconnect 
Select col1 from test
echo $var1
```

It is not replacing `l_count` with 12 even if I do:

```
echo $(echo $var1)
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: You have set `L_count=12` and tryign to access `l_count`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Inian that is a typo error..i used l_count for both

Comment: @Neha Sethi value is there in your table?

Comment: when you insert the value you are not in the scope where the `$l_count` variable is set and hence the value is not replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a code fragment in your database that you want to evaluate as a shell script.  You don't mention what shell you are using, I am guessing bash.

Bash contains a builtin function called `eval` to help you do that. I guess other shells probably have similar functionality.

So basically, try `eval echo $var1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks peder.Below command worked fine

eval "echo //$var1"